# scrapy can't submit form

Tags: python, html, scrapy, web-crawler

This is the webpage I want to scrape:
http://www.nalpdirectory.com/Page.cfm?PageID=34. I want to simulate submitting the form #resultDisplayOptionsForm with #customDisplayNum set to All, which will bring me a webpage with all listed items.

This is my code snippet:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formid='resultDisplayOptionsForm',
        formdata={'displayNum': '100000'}, #I tried 10, 20, 30 etc. none works
        dont_click=True,
        #clickdata={'id': 'customizeDisplaySubmitBtn'},
        callback=self.after_showAll
    )
def after_showAll(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

When I inspect the response, it always shows a failed page. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: first time I check someone using the `dont_click` argument.

Comment: what do you mean with "failed page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are missing the actual `POST` request to get the data.

If you check closely, the `POST` request url of the form is to [this site](http://www.nalpdirectory.com/cfc/SaveSearchResultDisplayOptions.cfc?method=doSaveOptions), while the **"response"** that you want is to [this site](http://www.nalpdirectory.com/Page.cfm?PageID=34), so there you can confirm that something is missing.

You are missing to execute a third request into the final site, in scrapy code, it would be like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formid='resultDisplayOptionsForm',
        formdata={'displayNum': '100000000'},  # I tried 10, 20, 30 etc. none works
        dont_click=True,
        # clickdata={'id': 'customizeDisplaySubmitBtn'},
        callback=self.after_showAll
    )

def after_showAll(self, response):
    yield FormRequest(
        url='http://www.nalpdirectory.com/Page.cfm?PageID=34',
        formdata={
            'currPage': '1',
            'checkedFormID': '',
        },
        callback=self.parse_real,
    )

def parse_real(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

Comment: Thank you eLRuLL!!! This is my first question in StackOverflow and it was answered perfectly. Appreciated!